# Supersized JS repeating background?

Tags: javascript, background, supersized

I've looked through the [Supersized Documentation](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/docs.html) but was unable to find a way to repeat a background horizontally, is there a way to achieve this? I would be looking for the same method as when using the css property [background-repeat: repeat-x;](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp)

Comment: Maybe you're using a wrong tool? Use CSS instead.

Comment: You could be possibly correct, I like using supersize though as it adds a bit of responsive-ness